# this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I Write code like this: in constructor

```
newTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); 
newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); 
newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick; 
newTimer.Start(); 


private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    SecondsToGo--; 
    if (SecondsToGo == 0) { 
        change();
        SecondsToGo= 3;
    }
    Timein.Text = SecondsToGo.ToString(); 
}
```

And change function is

```
public void change() {
    c = new List<TokenList>();
    for (int i =0;i<10 ;i++)
    {
        c.Add(new TokenList("hello", "Hi"));
    }
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
        longlistselector.ItemsSource.Clear();
        longlistselector.ItemsSource = c;
    }));
}
```

the long list selector items are still old values. How can i update those values?

Comment: No point in using BeginInvoke() at all.  Start there first.

Comment: Where are you instantiating `c`?

Comment: I asked `where` ;) My guess is that your re-using the same instance of `c` everytime. Either use an ObservableCollection and assign it only once to your `ItemSource`, or create a new instance of `c` every time

Comment: Thank You Mr. Kookiz. ObservableCollection  Made the difference. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your re-using the same instance of `c` everytime. If I remember correctly, the `ItemsSource` property of the LongListSelector uses an optimization that prevents you from re-assigning the same instance of an object (not to mention your call to `Clear()` on it that is clearly bogus). Either use an ObservableCollection and assign it only once to your ItemsSource, or create a new instance of `c` every time

Answer (score 0):

`DispatcherTimer` calls `Tick` method already on UI dispatcher (assuming you created it's object from UI dispatcher). You don't need to put it on UI dispatcher. Try your code without dispatcher.

```
public void change()
{
    for (int i =0;i<10 ;i++)
    {
        c.Add(new TokenList("hello", "Hi"));
    }
    longlistselector.ItemsSource.Clear();
    longlistselector.ItemsSource = c;
}
```